# Переключение dots при вертикальном свайпе в Slick. Как сделать?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Доброго времени суток.
Есть слайдер, в котором есть вертикальный свайп. Необходимо, чтобы при свайпе переключались индикаторы в .slick-dots. Самое интересное это, что при горизонтальном свайпе всё нормально. Страница находится [здесь](http://new.rofas.kz)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mobile-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    dots: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    arrows: false,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    vertical: true
  });
  $('.slick-dots>li').on('click', function() {
    var image_data = $(this).attr('id');
    var li_color = $('div[aria-describedby="' + image_data + '"]').data('color');
    $('.slick-dots>li>button').css({
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
    });
    $(this).find('button').css({
      backgroundColor: li_color
    });
  });
  $('.slick-dots>li:first-child').click();
});
```

```css
.slick-dots {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slick-dots {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12vh;
    right: 8vw;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .slick-dots li button {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
  }
}

.slick-dots .slide-active button {
  background-color: #e64e4e;
}

.slick-slide {
  height: 90vh !important;
}

.slick-slide img {
  margin-top: .5vh;
}

.mobile-slider {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-slider {
    display: block;
    height: 90vh;
  }
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline margin-top 35vh h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide h1 {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  color: #fff;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide p {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: #fff;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 20vw;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline-bottom {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide .mobile-inline-bottom a {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-roof {
  background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/roof-bg.png');
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-roof .mobile-inline-bottom p {
  margin-right: 5%;
  color: #e64e4e;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-fasad {
  background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/fasad-bg.png');
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-fasad .mobile-inline-bottom p {
  margin-right: 2vw;
  color: #f7a550;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-design {
  background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/design-bg.png');
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-design .mobile-inline-bottom p {
  margin-right: 2vw;
  color: #fedd32;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-industry {
  background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/industry-bg.png');
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-industry .mobile-inline-bottom p {
  margin-right: 2vw;
  color: #51b9f1;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-eco {
  background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/eco-bg.png');
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-eco .mobile-inline-bottom p {
  margin-right: 2vw;
  color: #70ca57;
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-stone {
  background-image: url('http://new.rofas.kz/images/stone-bg.png');
}

.mobile-slider .mobile-slide-stone .mobile-inline-bottom p {
  margin-right: 2vw;
  color: #956ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-slider">
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-roof" data-color="#e64e4e">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #e64e4e; font-family: 'ABold'">Roof</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <a ui-sref="roof" style="color: #e64e4e">Rofas Roof</a><img src="icons/right-arrow-roof.png" style="margin: 0"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-fasad" data-color="#f7a550">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #f7a550; font-family: 'ABold'">Facade</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Facade</p><img src="icons/right-arrow-fasad.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-design" data-color="#fedd32">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #fedd32; font-family: 'ABold'">Design</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Design</p><img src="icons/right-arrow-design.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-industry" data-color="#51b9f1">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #51b9f1; font-family: 'ABold'">Industry</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="icons/right-arrow-industry.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-eco" data-color="#70ca57">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #70ca57; font-family: 'ABold'">Eco</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="icons/right-arrow-eco.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-slide mobile-slide-stone" data-color="#956ccc">
    <div class="mobile-inline" style="margin-top: 40vh">
      <h1>Rofas</h1>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 3vw; color: #956ccc; font-family: 'ABold'">Stone</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="mobile-inline-bottom">
      <p>Rofas Industry</p><img src="icons/right-arrow-stone.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Голову уже сломал, никак не удается решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .slick-active:nth-of-type(1) > button {
      background-color: #e64e4e !important;
    }
    .slick-active:nth-of-type(2) > button {
      background-color: #f7a550 !important;
    }
    /* и так далее */
```